# Localizations of $\mathbb{Z} / (30)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, localization

I am trying to find all localizations of the ring $\mathbb{Z} / (30)$. To do this, I know that I need to find multiplicatively closed subsets of $\mathbb{Z} / (30)$, and then the localizations are of the form $W^{-1} \mathbb{Z} / (30)$, where $W$ is a multiplicatively closed subset. But is there any systematic way of finding all of the multiplicatively closed subsets? I can't seem to find a way of doing this. Also, as I am only looking for localizations up to isomorphism, do I need all of the multiplicatively closed subsets, or only some of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to consider the subsets of $\{2,3,5\}$.

Basically, if the multiplicative subset contains only units, then the localization is nothing but the ring itself. So you may think that basically we need to specify which non units we want to be inverted. Nonunits in $\mathbb{Z}/(30)$ are $0$ and the class of integers which are divisible by $2,3$ or $5$. Hence it is enough to specify which subset of $\{2,3,5\}$ you want to invert (i.e. take the subset and set $W$ to be the multiplicative set spanned by this subset). There are $8$ of these subsets.

Comment: What if we only inverted elements that are, say, powers of $6$? Wouldn't that also be a multiplicatively closed subset though, that is strictly smaller than any of the sets you identified?

Comment: Yes it would be a multiplicative subset. First note that $6^2=6$. Moreover, when you invert $6$, you also invert $2$ and $3$ since $\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$. So inverting $6$ and inverting $2$ and $3$ are the same thing.

Comment: I didn't notice that inverting $6$ also inverts $2$ and $3$. Thank you for clarifying that for me.

Comment: @rschwieb usually a ring has more than one maximal ideal so the complement of a maximal ideal contains non units. If it has only one maximal ideal, i.e. if it is a local ring then localizing at that maximal ideal gives the same ring.

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{Z}$. The complement of $(2)$ contains, for example, $3$ which is not a unit.

Comment: @Levent Sorry, you're right, I had the wrong end of the stick.